# How do I create a text box alert/ hover pop up text depending on form selection in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, erb

I have this code so far in `form.html.erb` but it doesn't work the way I want it to. It just shows the placeholder value.
What I want to do is: when the user selects A, I would like a text box beside the selection A showing some text to provide more detail about that selection.

```
<%= form.label :title %><br>
<%= form.select :title, ['A', 'B','C','D' ]%>
<%= form.text_field : Content, class:"form-control", placeholder:'text here', style:"#{'display: This is A' if form.object.title == 'A'}" %>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Hello @Eyeslandic, thanks for editing the content. I have also edited it to clarify what's happening. It basically doesn't work and just shows the placeholder. I would like to add multiple if statements for example, if the user selects B, some other content in the text box will be shown. I hope this is clear enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails Form Helpers don't do all thing on behalf of you, if you want to do some magic around the form, you have to put some javascript.

in your case, if you just want to show a simple alert to show selected option information, you could do like this:

```rb
 <% ruby_var = "this is ruby variable"; options = {
      "A": "I like ice cream and I like books",
      "B": "I like pizza and I do not like books",
      "C": ruby_var
    }.to_json
 %>

<%= form.select(:title, ['A', 'B','C','D' ], {}, :onChange =>"javascript: alert(#{options}[this.value]);")%>
```

if you want more, write your own js to manipulate dom elements

Comment: Thank you! This works! However, I wonder how to use some nested if statement for the alert.  For example, when A is selected -> "here are the details for choice A", and when B is selected -> "here are the details for choice B". I can't seem to find a workaround on the code for this output.

Comment: @user16453313 this code ``This is ${this.value}``  already did, when you selected A, `${this.value}` is A.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to explain it well. So when I say "Here are the details", I mean different content for each selection. Like: 
A=> I like ice cream and I like books
B => I like pizza and I don't like books. 
The detail doesn't have to include ${this.value}. I hope it's clear!

Comment: @user16453313 i updated my answer,  `option` here could be the data you get from db or on your controller logic, it's ruby.